# Stripe API Call from Google Sheets to Add Multiple Cards to Multiple Customers Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, stripe-payments, card

I have successfully added a card from google sheets to stripe through their API

```
function StripeAddCard(){
    var cardno = "4242424242424242";
    var cardexpmo = "42";
    var cardexpyr = "42";
    var url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_M0hfHRz4zizqes/sources";
    
    var params = {
     // method: "get",
      headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("sk_live_*************:")},
      payload: {
        "source[object]": "card",
        "source[number]": cardno, 
        "source[exp_month]": cardexpmo,
        "source[exp_year]": cardexpyr},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    //  limit: 2 //limit not working
    }
    
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
  
    //const json = response.getContentText();
    //const CustomerData = JSON.parse(json);
    //console.log(CustomerData.name);
    console.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

I am now attempting to example upon this to loop through a spreadsheet and gather all the appropriate values and then send them through the same API one at a time. Instead of a successful response, it returns this:

```
{ toString: [Function],
  getResponseCode: [Function],
  getContent: [Function],
  getHeaders: [Function],
  getContentText: [Function],
  getAllHeaders: [Function],
  getBlob: [Function],
  getAs: [Function] }
```

If successful, the response is like this:

```
{
  "id": "card_1LQElcG7pYQHkBLcGMk7wetP",
  "object": "card",
  "address_city": null,
  "address_country": null,
  "address_line1": null,
  "address_line1_check": null,
  "address_line2": null,
  "address_state": null,
  "address_zip": null,
  "address_zip_check": null,
  "brand": "MasterCard",
  "country": "US",
  "customer": "cus_M0hfHRz4zizqes",
  "cvc_check": null,
  "dynamic_last4": null,
  "exp_month": 42,
  "exp_year": 4242,
  "fingerprint": "irG4XOVMCwurPGDJ",
  "funding": "debit",
  "last4": "4242",
  "metadata": {
  },
  "name": null,
  "tokenization_method": null
}
```

Here is the code that is not working:

```
function StripeAddMultiCard(){
    var PaymentSSID = "********************";
    var WorkingSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(PaymentSSID);
    var WorkingSheet = WorkingSS.getSheetByName("StripeToAdd");
    
    var CardsToAdd = WorkingSheet.getRange(1, 1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() - 1;
    
    var DataSet = WorkingSheet.getRange(2,1,CardsToAdd,14).getValues;
    var cardname = "Adam";//col2
    var cardno = "06"; //col3
    var cardexpmo = "12"; //col13
    var cardexpyr = "12"; //col14
    var cardcvc = "123"; //col5
    var custID = "Temp"; //col12
    var url = "Temp"; //"https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_M0hfHRz4zizqes/sources";
    
    for (var i=0; i<3; i++){

      cardname = WorkingSheet.getRange(i+2,2).getValues()[0][0]; 
      cardno = WorkingSheet.getRange(i+2,3).getValues()[0][0];
      cardexpmo = WorkingSheet.getRange(i+2,13).getValues()[0][0];
      cardexpyr = WorkingSheet.getRange(i+2,14).getValues()[0][0];
      cardcvc = WorkingSheet.getRange(i+2,5).getValues()[0][0];
      custID = WorkingSheet.getRange(i+2,12).getValues()[0][0];
      url= "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/" + custID + "/sources"

      console.log("source[number]" + cardno); 
      console.log("source[exp_month]" + cardexpmo);
      console.log("source[exp_year]"+ cardexpyr);
      console.log("source[cvc]"+ cardcvc);
      console.log("source[name]"+ cardname);
      console.log("source[url]"+ url);
      
      var params = {
      // method: "get",
        headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("sk_live_*********************:")},
        payload: {
          "source[object]": "card",
          "source[number]": cardno, 
          "source[exp_month]": cardexpmo,
          "source[exp_year]": cardexpyr},
        muteHttpExceptions: true
      //  limit: 2 //limit not working
      }
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
      console.log(response);
      Utilities.sleep(51);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this actually has started to work. I did change the console log at the end to get the expected response as the 2nd function had console.log(response) and not console.log(response.getContentText()).

Answer (score 0):

While you figured out that the log at the end was not working i made some improvements. Getting and setting values from and to the sheet is time consuming. Now we get all the data in memory with one call and from there make the requests.

There is one more optimalisation we could do and that is to use .fetchAll(). Google makes parallel requests and returns all the responses at once. This will improve your speed a lot when you make many requests, but for now:

```
function StripeAddMultiCard() {
  var PaymentSSID = "********************";
  var WorkingSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(PaymentSSID);
  var WorkingSheet = WorkingSS.getSheetByName("StripeToAdd");
  var SheetValues = WorkingSheet.getRange(2, 1, WorkingSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 14).getValues();

  SheetValues.forEach(row => {
    var cardname = row[1] //Not used?
    var cardno = row[2]
    var cardexpmo = row[12]
    var cardexpyr = row[13]
    var cardcvc = row[4] //Not used?
    var custID = row[11]
    var url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/" + custID + "/sources"

    var params = {
      method: "post",
      headers: { Authorization: "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("sk_live_*********************:") },
      payload: {
        "source[object]": "card",
        "source[number]": cardno,
        "source[exp_month]": cardexpmo,
        "source[exp_year]": cardexpyr
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    }
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    console.log(response.getContentText());
  })
}
```

Comment: Would .fetchAll() be limited by the number of APIs that can be sent to Stripe per minute? I believe this is 20. I had removed cardname and cvc as they are not required and I was experiencing the errors, so I matched the equation with the SingleCard function that I had created. 

How would fetchAll() work within a forEach loop?

Comment: No you create an array with all the params (including the url) and then insert the array in the .fetchAll() if you can only do 20 in a minute then .fetchAll() will not give you any performance benefit. Besides that you have google's qoutas.